# Twisted multi-thread, signal handling

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted

I wrote a twisted program that handling request from TCP sockets and raw sockets. 
As the twisted doesn't support raw thread, I write the raw-socket select poll loop in a function named 'raw_socket_loop'. The main reactor program create a separate thread to run this loop by reactor.callInThread() function.

My problem is, I click control-C in the console but the reactor can not stop. I think the reactor's main thread receives this signal and handles well but the spawned thread doesn't receive this break signal. Is there is graceful shutdown suggestion for multi-thread reactor program?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Threads aren't interruptable.  You have to build a mechanism into the code running in a thread to receive shutdown notification and exit in response to it.

If you're using `select(2)` in the thread, then you can use the [self-pipe trick](http://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html) (which is how Twisted itself does this for its own thread-control needs).

However, if you're using `select(2)` in a thread, then maybe you should consider *not* using a thread and instead implementing [`IFileDescriptor`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IFileDescriptor.html) and using it with the reactor's [`IReactorFDSet`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorFDSet.html) implementation to get readiness events on it.  This way you avoid threads, you let the reactor actually implement the event loop, and you still get your raw sockets.

Comment: It's great! I implement an IReadDescritpor to read data from  raw socket and it works well now! thanks a lot.

Comment: Found a pretty good example of using the self-pipe trick in Python http://ruslanspivak.com/2012/06/24/self-pipe-trick/